# Query for Fetching Data Using Order Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have Below Database Table named cart_data

[image]

I want to Show the Record on the Basis of Requested Cart No

Kindly tell me the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM cart_data ORDER BY requested_cart_no"
```

or optionally assign the order ASC | DESC

```
"SELECT * FROM cart_data ORDER BY requested_cart_no DESC"
```

or, for a single record use 'WHERE' clause , the operator ( = | > | < | >= ...) and the value you need. es:

```
"SELECT * FROM cart_data WHERE requested_cart_no > 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe this query solve your problem

`Select * from cart_data where requested_card_non = 1`

Comment: Bro, Listen , I want to show that something like below
cart no 1
       3 products shown
cart no 2
       1 product show